# Passing multiple values in Kusto

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

The below first query (x) returns a column of 10 names, and then I want to run another query to find those names in another table and return the output of each row. how can I do that? I think I need something like a foreach statement:

```
let x = cluster('xcluster.kusto.windows.net').database('xdatabase').xtable
| limit 10
;
let y = cluster('ycluster.kusto.windows.net').database('ydatabase').ytable
| where Name has strcat("a",x)
| limit 10
;

Thank you.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your description correctly, you could try something like the following, which uses the `has_any()` function:

```
let x = 
    range x from 1 to 5 step 1
    | project strcat("a", x)
;
let y =
    range y from 1 to 100 step 1
    | extend y = strcat("a", y, ": something")
    | where y has_any(x)
;
y
```

This returns a table with a single column with the following string values:

```
a1: something
a2: something
a3: something
a4: something
a5: something
```